# issue using Singleton pattern with tkinter Photoimage/Tk in python

Tags: python, tkinter, singleton

Wrote the following code to display a chessboard using Tkinter in Python:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Gui(tk.Tk):
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls._instance.__initialized = False
        return cls._instance

def __init__(self):
    if self.__initialized:
        return
    self.__initialized = True
    super().__init__()

class Color(object):
    white =(0xff,0xff,0xff)
    black =(0x00,0x00,0x00)

class Tile(tk.PhotoImage):
    @staticmethod
    def putTile(image, color, width, height, coordinates):
        pix = "#%02x%02x%02x" % color
        coor = (coordinates[0]*width, coordinates[1]*height)
        line = "{" + " ".join([pix]*width) + "}"
        image.put(" ".join([line]*height),coor)

class Grid(tk.PhotoImage):
    def __init__(self,grid):
        super().__init__(width=10*len(grid), height=10*len(grid[0]))
        for x in range(len(grid)):
            for y in range(len(grid[x])):
                Tile.putTile(self,Color.white if grid[x][y]==1 else
                             Color.black,10,10,(x,y))

class ChessBoard(Grid):
    chessboard = 4 * ([4 * [0,1]] + [4 * [1,0]])
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self.chessboard)
```

So `Gui()` is implemented as a singleton pattern. Also `tk.Tk.__init__()` is made to be called only once, otherwice I got a window everytime `Gui()` was called.

I would expect the following to display a window with a chessboard:
**Case 1:**

```
label = tk.Label(Gui(), image=ChessBoard())
label.pack()
Gui().mainloop()
```

This creates an empty window without errors or warnings. A print statement shows that method `tilePut` is indeed called.

Only when I add an additional `Gui()` statement in my program, as shown below, everyting works perfectly and a chessboard is printed.

**Case 2:**

```
Gui()
label = tk.Label(Gui(), image=ChessBoard())
label.pack()
Gui().mainloop()
```

So I guess the `image.put` call requires a `Gui()` to exist. Though if I try the following code:

**Case 3:**

```
board = ChessBoard()
label = tk.Label(Gui(), image=board)
label.pack()
Gui().mainloop()
```

I get an error about calling `image.put` too soon. Considering I do not get this same error in case 1, I am surprised case 1 does not work. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: The indentation of `__init__` looks wrong in your question. Is it really indented all the way to the left?

Comment: You are adding an incredible amount of complexity that can be avoided by using more traditional coding techniques. What's the point of the singleton over just creating the root window once and saving the instance as a global?

Comment: @Parviz: nope, no copy-paste, i wrote it myself. I try to improve my coding, I only did scripting before. Btw, thanks for reformatting my question

Comment: @Bryan: I just like writing Gui() everywhere instead of keeping a reference to that gui=Gui(). Just experimenting. If it is bad practice, i will change it, though I am still curious about an explanation for the behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your questions boils down to two factors:

1. The root window must exist before you can create an image
2. You must keep a reference to the image or tkinter will destroy 
   the image data when it does garbage collection.

The proper way to use this code would be to first create an instance of `Gui`, then create `Chessboard` and save what is returned in a variable. You can then use these references in the rest of your code.

This is the common way to accomplish that:

```
root = Gui()
chessboard = ChessBoard()
label = tk.Label(root, image=chessboard)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Since you are defining `Gui` as a singleton, the following will also work. However, I think the use of a singleton adds complexity and makes the code less clear since it looks like you are creating three instances of `Gui`:

```
Gui()
chessboard = ChessBoard()
label = tk.Label(Gui(), image=chessboard)
label.pack()
Gui().mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I realized the first part of your answer and I took note of your comment on the use of a singleton pattern.
What function would the garbage collector use to figure out that no link is kept to the image data?